# MillenialMedia interstitial video ads in Appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-modules

I'm trying to display video ads in my Appcelerator Titanium Alloy app. I'm using Millenial Media currently. I used there module https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/791?816777609 but it doesn't seem to work with iphone 5 or Ipad Retna. I looked in the release notes and it is built with a 4.X SDK when they are now on 5.1. I'm assuming this is the main issue. Are there any alternatives? Has anyone found a different way to get this working?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to create your own module then (it's really not that difficult).

First, start off with the [admob module and see how they integrated it.](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/admob/mobile/ios) All they do is wrap the GADBannerView inside a TiUIView, then request an ad for each instance.

[Then integrate this tutorial on BannerAds from millenial media.](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/iOS-SDK/iOSBannerAds.html) Essentially all you have to do is exchange `GADBannerView` for `MMAdView` and GADRequest for `MMRequest`.

Comment: I actually started down this path shortly after posting it. Thanks for the links and description

Comment: Cool, hope that helps.